# How to implement an impersonation feature?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, impersonation

If you have used Gitlab - it has an impersonsation feature where if your user has the 'owner' role the can 'impersonate' any user that has been created on the system by clicking a button and see what they see.

I would like to understand how can one implement a feature like that? what is the software design / architecture for it.

I am planning to design and implement this functionality in Java, Spring and Tomcat using server side sessions and would prefer to roll-out my own impersonation feature instead of using a library

Answer (score 1):

If you want a specific solution that GitLab implemented in Ruby, you could take a look at the commit that introduced the feature: [Commit 3bb626f9 - refactor login as to be impersonation with better login/logout](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/commit/3bb626f91cb50bd2eff58681e22db942b7d6a087)

Please note that the security issue introduced on this commit was later fixed later: [GitLab Blog Post - Critical Security Release for GitLab 8.2 through 8.7](https://about.gitlab.com/2016/05/02/cve-2016-4340-patches/)

Otherwise, I think this question is too broad. 
I need some more details - Framework, Current Authentication mechanism, etc.

EDIT: 
I do not know Java Spring framework too well, but these links may help you:

1. [spring security (3.0.x) and user impersonation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337825/spring-security-3-0-x-and-user-impersonation)
2. [How to do impersonation in spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25546554/how-to-do-impersonation-in-spring)

Comment: what do you mean by framework? Current authentication mechanism is basic auth. Once I hear from you, I will update the question with relevant information

Comment: @andthereitgoes,  
- Regarding Framework - what language are you using? C#? JS? Ruby? going forward with it, what framework are you using on top of that? Example of that may be ASP.NET, Express, Ruby on Rails, Django, etc  
- Regarding Auth - Do you use sessions managed on the server to keep the auth related info? Or do you use something like JWT to keep it all in the client side?

Comment: @dev.shin thanks. i have added more clarification to the question, Java, Spring and Tomcat using server side sessions.

Comment: @andthereitgoes, I don't know Java Spring too much - I added some links that maybe helpful.